# Python says it can't find the file I am trying to rename even though it can read the file name

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im tryin to append a short string to every '.png' file.  But when I run it, it says cannot find the file.  But I know it's there and I can see it in the folder.

Is there anything I need to do?

Here is my script:

```
import os

for file in os.listdir("./pics"):
    if file.endswith(".png"):
        newFileName = "{0}_{2}{1}".format(*os.path.splitext(file) + ("z4",))
        os.rename(file, newFileName)
```

Here is the error message I get...02.png is the first file in the folder:

> fileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
> specified: '02.png' -> '02_z4.png'

It's odd though because it gets the filename, in this case, `02.png`.  So if it can read the file name, why can't it find it?

Thanks!

Comment: `02.png` doesn't exist relative to your cwd. `./pics/02.png` does, though.

Comment: What is cwd?  thanks!

Comment: cwd = Current Working Directory

Comment: @That1Guy oh sorry, that makes sense! :)  So do I need to use that command you mentioned, `os.path.join(directory, file)` directly before the line in my script that says, `os.rename(file, newFileName)` ?  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought my comment might be enough, but for clarity I'll provide a short answer.

`02.png` doesn't exist relative to your working directory. You need to specify the path to the file for `os.rename` so you need to include the directory.

```
import os

for file in os.listdir("./pics"):
    if file.endswith(".png"):
        newFileName = "/pics/{0}_{2}{1}".format(*os.path.splitext(file) + ("z4",)) # Notice the ./pics
        os.rename(os.path.join('pics', file), newFileName)
```

Comment: I'm so sorry but that didn't work...I do see that changed the error message from the one I originally received to this: `fileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '02.png' -> './pics/02_z4.png`

Answer (score 1):

The name returned from os.listdir() gives the filename, not the full path. So you need to rename pics/02.png to pics/02_zf.png. Right now you don't include the directory name.